# Solve returns empty list

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve these equations but Mathematica gives no answer.

```
X := 
  3/2 x (-((γ y (1 - z)^3 (-x^2 - y^2 + 1)^2)/z^3) + x^2 - y^2 - 1) - 
    (λ y z)/(1 - z);

Y := 
  -((3 γ (y^2 - 1) (1 - z)^3 (-x^2 - y^2 + 1)^2)/(2 z^3)) + 3/2 y (x^2 - y^2 + 1) + 
    (λ x z)/(1 - z);

Z := 
  3/2 ((1 - z) z (x^2 - y^2 + 1) - (γ y (1 - z)^4 (-x^2 - y^2 + 1)^2)/z^2);

Solve[X == Y == Z == 0, {x, y, z}]
```

> `{}`

What do I do?

Comment: `Reduce[{X == Y == Z == 0}, {x, y, z}]`

Comment: As a side note, it is considered bad form to use capital letters as declared variables. Or to use multi-letter variables that start with capital letters.

Comment: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. (or Reduce)

Comment: @Young Do you Know another method?

Comment: @milad , @Young This system can be solved with `Reduce`!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the documentation on `Solve`.

Under Details:

[image]

`{}` means that your system has no solutions in general.

`Reduce` does give a solution, but notice that it comes with the specific condition that `λ == 0`.  For general `λ` there is no solution.

`Solve` gives generic solutions only.  Another excerpt from the documentation:

> `Solve` gives generic solutions only. *Solutions that are valid only when continuous parameters satisfy equations are removed.* Other solutions that are only conditionally valid are expressed as `ConditionalExpression` objects.